# fill multiple missing values with series based on index values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

consider the `pd.DataFrame` `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        [np.nan, 1,      np.nan],
        [2,      np.nan, np.nan],
        [np.nan, np.nan, 3     ],
    ], list('abc'), list('xyz'))

df
```

[image]

and the `pd.Series` `s`

```
s = pd.Series([10, 20, 30], list('abc'))
```

---

How do I fill in missing values of `df` with the corresponding values of `s` based on the index of `s` and the index of `df`

For example:

- `df.loc['c', 'x']` is `NaN`
- `s.loc['c']` is `30`

***expected result***
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pandas handles this on a column basis with no issues.  Suppose we had a different `s`

```
s = pd.Series([10, 20, 30], ['x', 'y', 'z'])
```

then we could

```
df.fillna(s)

      x     y     z
a  10.0   1.0  30.0
b   2.0  20.0  30.0
c  10.0  20.0   3.0
```

But that's not what you want.  Using your `s`

```
s = pd.Series([10, 20, 30], ['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

then `df.fillna(s)` does nothing.  But we know that it works for columns, so:

```
df.T.fillna(s).T

      x     y     z
a  10.0   1.0  10.0
b   2.0  20.0  20.0
c  30.0  30.0   3.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a NumPy approach -

```
mask = np.isnan(df.values)
df.values[mask] = s[s.index.searchsorted(df.index)].repeat(mask.sum(1))
```

Sample run -

```
In [143]: df
Out[143]: 
     x    y    z
a  NaN  1.0  NaN
b  2.0  NaN  NaN
d  4.0  NaN  7.0
c  NaN  NaN  3.0

In [144]: s
Out[144]: 
a    10
b    20
c    30
d    40
e    50
dtype: int64

In [145]: mask = np.isnan(df.values)
     ...: df.values[mask] = s[s.index.searchsorted(df.index)].repeat(mask.sum(1))
     ...: 

In [146]: df
Out[146]: 
      x     y     z
a  10.0   1.0  10.0
b   2.0  20.0  20.0
d   4.0  40.0   7.0
c  30.0  30.0   3.0
```

Please note that if the index values of `s` are not sorted, we need to use extra argument `sorter` with `searchsorted`.

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
def fillnull(col):
    col[col.isnull()] = s[col.isnull()]
    return col

df.apply(fillnull)
```

Note that it's less efficient than @Brian's way (9ms per loop versus 1.5ms per loop on my computer)